# dictionaries in loop using a list of strings - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

How can you iterate through a list of multiple dictionaries?

```
list_country = ['dict_DAN', 'dict_FRA']

dict_DAN ={ 'APPROVEDTXT':  'GODKENDT', 'REVIEWTXT':  'KONTROLLERET AF'}
dict_FRA ={ 'APPROVEDTXT':  'Aprov', 'REVIEWTXT': 'Controllier'}

for country in list_country:
    print country

    for (key,item) in country.items:
            print key
            print item`
```

> this throws an error:
>         File "", line 9, in 
>       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

I want the code to use dict_DAN on the first iteration and dict_FRA on the second iteration. How can achieve this?

Comment: Put each dictionary in another one using the string as the key.

Comment: [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you need the names in `list_country` for something else, you should put the actual dicts in there instead:

```
dict_DAN ={ 'APPROVEDTXT':  'GODKENDT', 'REVIEWTXT':  'KONTROLLERET AF'}
dict_FRA ={ 'APPROVEDTXT':  'Aprov', 'REVIEWTXT': 'Controllier'}

list_country = [dict_DAN, dict_FRA]
```

Or, you could make that a dict itself:

```
list_country = {'dict_DAN': dict_DAN, 'dict_FRA': dict_FRA]

for name, country in list_country.items():
    ...
```

Comment: of course - the quotes make it a string. if i do want to use the names the answer below by @moliware will do the trick. thankyou!